# How to polling the changes to a SQL Server table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I monitor a SQL Server database for inserts of new values into a table without using triggers or modifying the structure of the database in any way? The polling database will only have insert operations.

My plan is to write a scheduled job on SQL Server that checks the table every 30 min. If the table has any new rows inserted, then I need to insert those new values into another table.

Please suggest, how can I achieve this requirement?

Thanks,
Sameek

Comment: Do you need to capture updates also?

Comment: @ElectricLlama:no,only capture insert,basically it's an audit table.

Comment: This is the **perfect job** for a **insert trigger** ..... why can't you use triggers?

Comment: I totally agree with @marc_s. If you can change the insert statement, you can use the `OUTPUT` clause in order to write the new record in some place.